# Using unsupported compilers in Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, clang

Does anyone know how to set up llvm3.1 for use in Xcode 4.4? is it as simple as pointing Xcode at Clang in the bin directory of the compiler?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd put a bounty on this if SO would let me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just set `CC=/path/to/clang` in an xcconfig file.